# Java list check if an element is duplcate and mark it

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda

I have a list of objects, in that list could be duplicate elements and I need to check each element in that list with all elements the list, if I found a duplicate element I have to mark it as duplicate.

I did this with normal for loop as show :

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.size() - 1; i++) {
    Record record = records.get(i);
    for (int k = i + 1; k < records.size(); k++) {
        Record currentRecord = records.get(k);
        if (RecordsParser.isDuplicateRecord(record, currentRecord)) {
            currentRecord.setValid(false);
            currentRecord.setErrorCode(ErrorCodes.DUPLICATE_ID);
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is : Is there any way to this logic with lambda expresion in a cleanner way ?

Comment: What's your endgame here? What do you do with the resulting list?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried ?

Comment: I will never understand why people think using _lambda_ is cleaner or nicer... The magic going on behind the scenes make it (in my opinion) dirtier

Comment: Yes you can do that with a lambda expression however I´m with @ParkerHalo on this one. Lambda expressions might be a lot faster to code but cleaner? No.

Comment: @Kayaman, just pass the list to another service.

Comment: @ParkerHalo, well yes...behind the scenes make it dirtier ...but I need performance...this is the reason why I tried to use lamda expresion.

Comment: But lambda expressions don't magically improve performance. You're more likely to worsen performance than improve it, if you don't know what you're doing. And you, you don't know what you're doing. Wouldn't it be just easier to remove all the duplicates before sending them off or are you going to process the dupes somehow as well?

Comment: @Kayaman, this is the problem, I just need to mark them as duplicate..not to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using lamda for something like this because as ParkerHalo said lamda expressions are not cleaner always. Your implementation has the worst complexity which is O(n^2). If I have well understand the problem I would use the following implementation for something more efficient (O(n)) and cleaner:

```
for (Element e : records) {
 if (set.add(e) == false) {
    e.setValid(false);
    e.setErrorCode(ErrorCodes.DUPLICATE_ID);
 }
```

}

Comment: Your example is good, but not for me. I have to check if 2 element are duplicates based on 2 field of elements.

Comment: Sorry then, may I did not get your requirements. May you give us an example?

Comment: @FlorinLei Why can't you make `equals` that returns true on the same premise as `RecordsParser.isDuplicateRecord`?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain my thoughts to this as clear as I can, but since I don't know what your `Record` class looks like, I might as well miss the topic.

As Dimitris stated, you have a complexity of `O(n²)` which is really bad for performance. Your goal should be to reach linear complexity `O(n)` or at least `O(n*log(n))`.

---

**How could you achieve that?**

- Use a `HashSet` to store the elements one by one
- If your hash function is good the lookup of an element will (usually) be constant `O(1)`
- Iterating over every single element with a constant lookup will result in a total complexity of `O(n)`

---

**Small example:**

```
class Record
{
    // The records are compared with these fields:
    int field1;
    int field2;

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        // ** You'll have to think about a good hash function for your example!**
        return 31 * field1 + 17 * field2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        // You'll have to adapt your equals method to your own record class
        if (!(obj instanceof Record))
            return false;
        Record other = (Record) obj;
        return this.field1 == other.field1 && this.field2 == other.field2;
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
HashSet<Record> set = new HashSet<>();
for(Record r : records)
{
    // If your hashCode function is good this will most likely be O(1)
    if (set.contains(r))
    {
        // You found a duplicate. Handle it here accordingly.
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // No duplicate, add it to the set. (Good hashCode --> mostly O(1) )
        set.add(r);
    }
}
```

Please note that this is only a vague example and that you'll have to adapt your `hashCode` and `equals` methods accordingly!